# Angular reusable component

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm creating a foreign language learning app in Angular 15. I have a lot of pages/components with different content. I thought that I will add a possibility of adjusting the font type, size etc for each page/component. I do not want to repeat the same code on each of the pages and thought that it would be best to create a separate component called `reading.settings`.

How can the `reading.settings` component be able to change font size, font type on a different component?

Does anyone have an idea how to implement something like this? Is it possible to do with Input and Output? If so then how?

Comment: you could probably use a service to store those values from that component. And from any other component, use the values from that service.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main features in Angular is the DI. Thanks to the Dependency Injection pattern, you are able to inject a dependency in more than a resource. Starting from your observation, I want to be clear about a thing: the @Input / @Output decorators (for property binding and event binding respectively) are used for sharing data between components that have a parent / child relationship into your widget tree. This means that it's not the way to go when you have to share data across components (or other elements) that are far away each other in the widget tree.

Let's assume the most simple scenario: you have to use the same font size in each component, and these settings will be handled through the ReadingSettingsComponent:

- The ReadingSettingsComponent will hold the form for handling font size and other stuff you are interested in
- A ReadingSettingService will hold the related font data into it's own properties (consider the use of a BehaviorSubject for having a default settings object, if you are familiar with RxJS and ReactiveX in general)
- The ReadingSettingsComponent will receive through injection the instance of ReadingSettingService. Remember that Angular provides a Hierarchical DI, but by default, you are going to use that as a flat DI so the service will share the same data across all the components that you have in the tree
- Other components that need to adjust the font size and other stuff you are handling with the service, will have the same instance of that service injected

If you need a specific font size / color / something for each widget, you can use a Map that has a key for each component and an object that hold those specific settings.